# Anchor navigation using the <a> tag inside a react component

Tags: html, reactjs, anchor

I'm attempting to set up anchor navigation in one of my page components inside my react app.

I'm trying to mimic the same functionality as seen [here on draft.js](https://draftjs.org/docs/getting-started#installation) where it uses sub headers as anchors (with the link icon next to it), which is also reflected in the URL.

As a reference I'm looking at http://www.tagindex.net/html/link/a_name.html

So I went ahead and tried implementing using the `name` attribute

```
  <List.Item>
    <a href="#createqueryschema">Create Query Schema</a>
  </List.Item>
```

Then the subheader it should jump to

```
<Header>
  <a name="createqueryschema">Create Query Schema</a>
  <Header.Subheader style={{ marginTop: "20px", fontSize: "1rem" }}>
    BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH
  </Header.Subheader>
</Header>
```

I'm rendering this list and subheader on a page called `/overview`, so in theory when I click on the item in the list it should jump to the `Create Query Schema` subheader AND reflect `/overview#createqueryschema` in the URL.

However, it is trying to navigate to page `/createqueryschema`. I'm not sure why/how it's trying to navigate to a new page when it should just be appending the # and the `name` attribute.

EDIT: It's also not jumping to the desired element

I have a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zk0970zypl) setup to further explain. Click docs on the top of the menu bar, which will take you to the page with the anchor nav. If you click any of the two anchors under the `Overview` section then corresponding `<Header>` is not scrolled to.

EDIT: **UPDATED for better explanation for routing issue**

I’m still having some trouble setting up an anchor element for same page navigation.
My app is already using hash router for another reason, so my base page `/home/#/`
Each other page would look like this `/home/#/page1` `/home/#/page2`

For example I’m using the in-page anchor navigation on `page2`
I’m creating a link to the named anchor below

```
   <List.Item>
    <a href="#some-random-header">Random Header</a>
  </List.Item>
```

Then create the named anchor using `id` attribute
`<Header id="some-random-header">Random Header Section</Header>`

When I click on the link, it tries to navigate to a new page with url `/home/#/some-random-header` INSTEAD of `/home/#/page2#some-random-header`

Comment: it's working for me if in open in the new tab.

Comment: @eramit2010 using chrome? I've tried this with every browser. It won't jump to any of the elements

Comment: yes, I am using chrome. did you try using this https://zk0970zypl.codesandbox.io/overview url?

Comment: Hmmm, that does indeed work, strange. But in my actual implementation the URL issue still is a problem. It's like it forgets `/overview` is the base of the page and instead tries to navigate to a new page when it really should just `/overview#query-something`

Answer (score 7):

Normally the # is used for an Id, however id's are not used in React. What you can do is create a ref. Then you can create a method onClick to scroll to the ref when the ref is clicked

So you could try something like:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const Component = () => {
   const myRef = useRef();
   const handleClick = () => {
      window.scrollTo(0, myRef.current.offsetTop)
   }
   return ( 
      <>
      <List.Item>
         <p onClick={handleClick}>Create Query Schema</p>
      </List.Item>
      <div name="createqueryschema" ref={myRef} >Create Query Schema</div> 
      </>
)

}
```

Comment: So the `id`'s would work correctly with anchors if they are outside of any react related component, so just vanilla html tags like `<p>` and such?

Comment: yes you can in html. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Linking_to_another_section_on_the_same_page

Comment: Perhaps this will be a solution for me as well https://github.com/rafrex/react-router-hash-link

Comment: @DJ2 also I would if you want to navigate to another route that you use Link instead of the anchor tag in React. Link will be rendered to an a element in the DOM but will make sure the navigation is within your routes in React. Otherwise it could be you navigate to a page other page outside of your app. I've had this problem before.