# How to scroll to an element in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, react-hooks, single-page-application

I am building a SPA in React and I need to make the navigation scroll to the the page sections when it is clicked, like we do with anchor tags in html.

I found this suggestion using `ref` and it seems to work:
[Anchor navigation using the <a> tag inside a react component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56446765/anchor-navigation-using-the-a-tag-inside-a-react-component)

The problem is I don't know how to do that in separate components.

These are my components:

[image]

So, I have all these functional components as `Layout`'s children. My navigation, which has the items referring to some of these components, is inside `Header`:

[image]

This is my navigation, what is inside `Header`. Since it is a single page application, what I want to do is when I click on `Menu` the page scrolls until the menu section (Menu Component), when I click on `Reviews` it scrolls to `CustomerReviews` and so on.

Since `Navigation` is inside `Header`, what I believe I would have to do is to create a method within `Layout` to be able to access the other components, but I would have to trigger this method from within `Header`. No problem with that. But I don't know how to make the page scroll to the component since I can't just put a `ref` in a component. Like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do that? Even if it is without `ref`, this was just what made sense so far.

Comment: Are you familiar with React contexts and Providers? The concepts are exactly what you are looking for. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: @Steve Hynding actually no. But I'll take a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [React Scroll](https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll) and it is working fine. I was looking for a native solution, but since I couldn't find it yet this package does the job.

Comment: Ah, yes. Native (not react-native, mind you) solutions are not very common in React. I highly recommend Vue.js over React if you're looking for 1st and or 2nd party supported solutions to common use cases.